# MailChimp in Elementor - HTTP 404 - The requested resource could not be found

Tags: mailchimp, elementor

I am facing an issue with MailChimp in Elementor:

[The issue when I am trying to subscribe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60NvM.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPKm7.png)

FYI:
Lately I revoke the previous API key and added another one, however integration looks fine.

Any ideas would be really appreaciated !
Please help!